# How to make a custom dictionary on Android

Tags: android

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on making a custom 100 word dictionary app?

Here is the app design I had in mind.

1. Splash Screen
2. Main Screen

   - Search Option at top of screen
   - List from A - Z of words and definitions

     - When an end of the A section comes, the next line would be a capital B at a larger font level

I looked at the Dev Guide section but I am a little confused as to all the parts needed.

Comment: There is a dictionary app example on the android developer site that you might want to look into: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Hope this gets you started:

- Splash screen, see here: http://blogactivity.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/writing-splash-screens-the-right-way/
- Dictionary part, take a look at the example in the development kit, as @Craigy suggests.
- Having different kinds of rows in a list (to create your definition/capital letter layout) can be accomplished by overriding `getItemViewType()` and `getItemViewTypeCount()` in a custom adapter, and plugging that to a `ListView`. You can find examples if you google around, and there's always the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int)

Answer (score 1):

The link given by Craigy doesn't work anymore, however there is a new one on the official website [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html), I think it is pretty thorough. Hope it helps!